# add Sharing with Airdrop to Spritekit game

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, airdrop

i want to add Airdrop sharing to my spritekit game

It dosent work using this code:

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Comment: Where does this code exist ? What is `objectsToShare contain` ? Any console output ?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the issue is where you have the code you posted. You possibly have it in `viewDidLoad` of your `UIViewController`.

Do this in your `UIViewController` :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   // assuming you are creating objectsToShare here or before this point

    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]

}
```

I believe the issue is that the view is not fully configured when you are trying to add your `UIActivityViewController`.

I believe that the bounds and some other properties of the view are not yet properly configured in the viewDidLoad method, which results in a failure to display it.